# SQL to add an entire column to another column with duplicated values of rest of the columns?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, google-bigquery

I have written a Bigquery SQL to generate the following:

```
id1    id2    orders    price
 x1     y1     100        1
 x2     y2     200        2
 x3     y3     300        3
```

Expected:

```
id1        orders    price
 x1         100        1
 x2         200        2
 x3         300        3
 y1         100        1
 y2         200        2
 y3         300        3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id1, orders, price 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([id1, id2]) id1
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'x1' id1, 'y1' id2, 100 orders, 1 price UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x2', 'y2', 200, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x3', 'y3', 300, 3 
)
SELECT id1, orders, price 
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([id1, id2]) id1
-- ORDER BY id1
```

with result

```
Row id1 orders  price    
1   x1  100     1    
2   x2  200     2    
3   x3  300     3    
4   y1  100     1    
5   y2  200     2    
6   y3  300     3
```

Comment: Much more BigQuery'ish.  And probably more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achievable using `union`

```
select id1, orders, price from test 
union all
select id2, orders, price from test
```